# Is there a way to convert a cryptocurrency to another cryptocurrency without first converting it to a regular currency? Python - Coinbase

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use the [coinbase api](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2) to buy and sell various cryptocurrency through a python program.

I have just started experimenting with this api, and haven't even been able to find a way to convert cryptocurrencies or a way to find the conversion rate, to see for example Bitcoin -> Etherum. I have tried replacing the string below, 'BTC-USD' with 'BTC-ETH' and it calls an error saying the pair don't exist. I know I can convert the BTC price to USD and then convert that to ETH, but that won't solve the problem of converting the currencies without having to convert it to a regular currency.

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
client = Client(<api_key>, <api_secret>)

rates = client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-USD')
```

If you are going to suggest an alternative, please note that I picked coinbase because it's minimum trading amount is $2, not a lot. Thanks for the help.